# How to retrieve objects from NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am new to iPhone development. I am parsing XML data and storing its details in a custom object. I have a product class which has product id, product name, etc and I store this in an object. This object is stored in an `NSMutableArray`.

I want to display the name of each product in a table row. How can I retrieve a particular object name from the `NSMutableArray`?

Answer (score 2):

Your question would be more clear if you put up some code you have now, but here are some ideas...

```
Product * product = (Product *)[array objectAtIndex:0]; //this gives you the first product in the array
```

And maybe...

```
//print out the name of each product
for (Product * product in array)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", product.name);
}
```

Comment: Note that there’s no need for the `(Product *)` cast.

Comment: Hmm...yea you're right. I think I started doing that because of compiler warnings, but maybe newer compilers don't complain anymore.

Comment: You can always assign a value of type `id` to an Objective-C object variable without a type cast and, conversely, you can always assign an Objective-C object to a variable of type `id` without a type cast.